# IProfileService and Tenant

Tags: identityserver4

We have multiTenant support, where user can belong to more then one tenant and in each tenant he may have different Roles,
Client application uses acr_values to pass the tenant information.
Based on this information a Role claim need to be added in Iprofileservice 
please suggest how I can do that..
I saw lots of post related to same topic but none has the full information
I am using IdentityServer4.

Comment: Any Update?, Need to get ACR_values in the iProfileService for Tenant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to get the acr values from the validated request property in the `ProfileDataRequestContext` context:

```
            string acr_values = context?.ValidatedRequest.Raw.Get("acr_values");
```

Note that `ValidatedRequest` may be null depending on the endpoint that is being requested.

Comment: we are passing tenant  in acr_values  from oidc-client, with implicit flow,
oidc-client does silent refresh also,
will this value be available for silent refresh

Comment: HI I got this detail on Login request but on UserInfo endpoint , these values are blank.
Let me tell you the complete scenario,

Comment: I am getting UseraccessId in the ACR_Values, Based on it, I am getting some information from Database and adding as cliam to user along with UserAccessId itself, a user can have multiple UserAccessId and data for specific UserAccessId Need to be return.
this all is working on ProfileService
But on UserInfo endpoint this ProfileService is called and as the USerInfo endpoint is called automatically from client library I dont have nay control over it, So How can I set the claims for UserAccessId there too?

Comment: Issue is solve, If the claims are added in authorization end point then no need to add them in userinfo end point,
Checked the caller property of the context and conditionally adding the claim.